# What is this extremely large brown fungus with white edges?

Tags: identification, fungus

[This](https://www.flickr.com/photos/lumeng/21355577620) is a huge fungus specimen I found along the [Obsidian Trail](http://www.fs.usda.gov/recarea/willamette/recarea/?recid=4457) near Bend, Oregon. I come across this type of fungus all the time in the Western Cascades mountain area, but this is by far the largest specimen I have ever seen.  It is really huge, perhaps as large as 1.5 feet wide. What species exactly is this?  Is it [tinder conk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fomes_fomentarius)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd identify it as one of the Ganodermas - these are particularly associated with foot and butt rot of woody plants, usually trees. The white rim is not uncommon in various of these, and the area beneath the 'cap' or top should be white. Not sure about those white/green lumps on the top though, never seen those before (see comments below - I reckon that's right, they are mirrored sunglasses...)

http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/diagnose/plant/deciduous/hickory/branchesfungi.html

UPDATED ANSWER

In theory, yes, though I'd rather say it doesn't seem to be toxic. Certainly some of the Ganodermas are used in traditional medicines. However, you know the old saying about mushroom collectors/eaters... link below (scroll down) gives some very good advice

http://www.na.fs.fed.us/stewardship/pubs/ediblefungi/ediblefungi.htm

Comment: I very unscientifically would identify the two lumps as a pair of sunglasses, presumably positioned by OP, either for artistic reasons, to show the size of the fungus or simply for fun.

Comment: Oh my word, you're right - they must be mirror ones, reflecting the sky/leaves...! I just couldn't see that till you mentioned it, thanks Stephie

Comment: LOL; Yeah, I put my glasses on it to contrast the sheer size of it.

Comment: @MengLu - see updated answer

Comment: For the benefit of my curious mind, what will be the practical procedure to effectively get a more exact identification -- what species is it -- given the general identification of a Ganoderma?

Comment: @MengLu Difficult to say - I'm a horticulturalist, not a mycologist, so I only know about these from the tree's point of view, rather than the fungus itself. You could Google images of Ganodermas, but the trouble is, finding one that looks exactly like yours isn't easy - there are variations in appearance even in the some variety...